# como exibir informações por params de um array de objetos em um componente no React JS

Tags: javascript, react

Eu tenho dois arquivos, ListCurses e CardCurses, no ListCurses a tenho um array de objetos e estou tentando perccorer e exibir as informações em outro componente (CardCurses) por props, mas a página retorna essa mensagem de erro " TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined  ". Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato, obrigado!

CardCurses.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card } from "antd";

const { Meta } = Card;

function CardCurses(props) {
  return (
    <Card
      hoverable
      style={{ width: 200, height: 240, padding: "10px" }}
      cover={<img alt="example" src={props.text.image} />}
    >
      <Meta title={props.text.title} description={props.text.descricao} />
    </Card>
  );
}

export default CardCurses;
```

ListCurses

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../CardCurses/CardCurses";

function ListCurses() {
   const cursos = [
    {
      title: "React JS",
      descricao: "React é legal",
      image: "https://pt-br.reactjs.org/logo-og.png"
    },
    {
      title: "React Native",
      descricao: "React Native é legal",
      image: "https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*GkR93AAlILkmE_3QQf88Ug.png"
    },
    {
      title: "Antd",
      descricao: "Antd é legal",
      image: 
      "https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/KDpgvguMpGfqaHPjicRK.svg"
    }
   ];

  const returnCurses = cursos.map((curse, i) => {
  return (
      <div key={i}>
        <Card text={curse} />
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{returnCurses}</div>;
}


export default ListCurses;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo você fazer o seguinte teste, passe cada valor para o seu "CardCurses" como uma props em separado, desta forma:

```
<Card title={curse.title} descricao={curse.descricao} image={curse.image}/>
```

Altere o seu "CardCurses" para desestruturar as props recebidas, seu código alterado seria este:

```js
const CardCurses = ({title, descricao, show }) => {
 return (
    <Card
      hoverable
      style={{ width: 200, height: 240, padding: "10px" }}
      cover={<img alt="example" src={image} />}
    >
      <Meta title={title} description={descricao} />
    </Card>
  );
}
```